# Can I use Angular property binding within an SVG defs block?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, svg

I am using Angular-7. I have a simple component for rendering the background of an icon image. It comprises a block of SVG code in the template which essentially renders a filled rectangle. The application can instantiate about twenty of these data driven components.

Originally, the background rectangle had a fill color which was bound to a property within the component which was assigned at construction time. Now, I'm looking to "pizz-azz" it up a bit by applying a linear gradient whose colors depend on the icon sub-type. In other words, I would like to use Angular property binding on the `stop-color` attribute of the linear gradient's `stop` element.

**Parent Template Snippet - Multiple Icon Creation**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let node of myNodes">
  <my-node-component [nodeInfo]=node></my-node-component>
</ng-container>
```

**Template Snippet of *my-node-component***

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 80 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient1" x1=0 y1=0 x2=0 y2=1>
      <stop offset=0 style.stop-color="{{color1}}" />
      <stop offset=1 style.stop-color="{{color2}}" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <g>
    <rect width="80" height="80" rx="5" ry="5"
      style="stroke-width:0"
      fill="url(#Gradient1)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Component Class Snippet of *my-node-component***

```typescript
@Input() nodeInfo: INodeInfo;  

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.color1 = this.nodeInfo.color1;
  this.color2 = this.nodeInfo.color2;
}
```

Note that the property binding itself is fine, as is the use of `ngOnInit` to access a component's `@Input` parameters.

What happens is that the first component is instantiated and appears to be correctly bound to the property values, `this.color1` and `this.color2`. However, all of the remaining icon components when instantiated, are apparently bound to the same first property value colors resulting in every icon having the same color gradient. As I said, when property binding was used directly on the on the rectangle's "fill" element, every icon colored correctly. That tells me that Angular's `*ngFor` iterator is behaving correctly.

Perhaps I have not understood the scope of a "defs" block correctly. It's as if the contents of "defs" are all "static" to the component? I am unable to verify this hypothesis in either Angular or SVG tutorials. There are one or two blogs and questions which hint about using multiple `linearGradient` declarations - but it is not clear if this applies here? Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: How many elements with id="Gradient1" are you creating. If the answer is more than one then that's invalid.

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson, As said, it's about 20. When you say invalid, can you explain further?

Comment: Per https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 **This name must be unique in a document.**

Comment: Ah of course. Many thanks @RobertLongson.